# Hypothesis testing in non-parametric regression

Tags: regression, time-series, inference, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

Say I have two processes/time series, $X = (X_{t_{1}},X_{t_{2}},\dots , X_{t_{n}})$ and $Y = (Y_{t_{1}},Y_{t_{2}},\dots , Y_{t_{n}})$ observed at times $t_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots, n$ where $0 < t_1 < t_2 \dots < t_n < T$.

I'm interested in the regression model
$$
Y_{t_{i}} = \alpha(t_i) + \beta(t_i)X_{t_i} + \epsilon_{t_i}.
$$

**Specifically I am interested in the sample paths of $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$.**

I don't really want to assume any structure for the errors so I decided to fit a non-parametric local linear regression model to give the sample paths as the arg min of the following equation
$$
(\hat{\alpha}(t) , \hat{\beta}(t)) =  \arg \min_{\alpha,\beta} \sum_{i=1}^{n} K \left( \frac{t-t_i}{h}\right) \left( Y_{t_i} - (\alpha + \beta X_{t_{i}}) \right)^2.
$$
Where $K(\cdot)$ is some kernel function and $h$ is the bandwidth.

**My Question: Is there any principled way to test the hypothesis that $\alpha(t) = 0$ for some intervals $I \subset [0,T]$?**

Any advice most appreciated!

Comment: Do you also want to add the continuity constraints that $\lim \alpha(\tau) = 0$ as $\tau \rightarrow I$ from below or above, writing a little sloppily?

Comment: Interesting! I didn't think about that I am open to both. Would the addition of the continuity constraint make it easier?

Comment: Probably harder, as you'd have to adjust your local linear regression model in such a way as to achieve the constraint.  But it seems to me somehow more reasonable, given that the local linear fit is continuous, to compare it to another continuous function.

Comment: Agreed, that makes sense!